# using 'a' with plural noun

Tags: grammar, articles

Articles are really tricky subject in English grammar.  Can you explain why using an article with a plural noun in the following sentence?

**These are just a few ideas.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article 'a' is **not** related to the noun *ideas* here, it is a part of the idiomatic expression 'a few' (= several) which governs the noun 'ideas'. Consider 'a few' working like 'several' or '(**is** just) a small bunch of'.